# Accessing NTFS Alternate Data Streams with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, stream, ntfs

I am writing a VBScript that I would like to be able to alter the Zone Identifier, and add Extended Attributes to various files with. Is this possible without the use addons, or something like the below?

```
objShell.run("type %windir%\notepad.exe > %windir%\calc.exe:notepad.exe")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle ADS like other files:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("file.exe:Zone.Identifier")
f.WriteLine "[ZoneTransfer]" & vbNewLine & "ZoneId=3"
f.Close

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("file.exe:Zone.Identifier", 1)
WScript.Echo f.ReadAll
f.Close
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers, Couldn't find this on msdn, do you have a reference also?

Comment: Only [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since the filesystem dictates the `filename:streamname` syntax I figured that there'd be no reason for it to not work, though, so I ran a quick test, and found that it does behave as you'd expect.

Comment: Ah, darn it... Found that article too, but figured it wouldn't work as that was in C++.Thanks Again Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: Is there a variation of this code to delete the ADS? I tried `fso.DeleteFile("file.exe:Zone.Identifier")` and `fso.DeleteFile("file.exe:Zone.Identifier:$DATA")` and got `Bad file name or number`

Comment: @LesFerch It seems that there is no simple way to delete an ADS directly (usng FSO), but it is possible indirectly (using `wscript.shell`, and exex/run). The simplest (still indirect) way to delete a specific ADS seems to be using powershell's `Remove-Item` with `-Stream`, so launching powershell.exe with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and `-Command "& {Remove-Item ...}"`. Alternatively, you can overwrite the ADS with an empty file using FSO, which can be good enough sometimes. It's certainly good enough to prevent a warning caused by the MOTW.

Comment: @GianSinghSarao Yes, I came to the same conclusion. I actually ended up doing the project in C#, where there was no problem deleting the ADS, but I did see that setting it empty in VBScript also had the desired effect. Thanks for confirming.